# What connector to use to non-permanently fix wires to large switch terminals?

Tags: switches, wire

I have a rather old rotary switch I want to use in a project. I want to connect wires to the terminals but would prefer not to solder directly to the switch. What connector is good for this?

[image: The switch]

The switch (the terminals are about 2.5mm)

Comment: Well, one could use "crocodiles"... Not very robust though. Ot these mini hook clip connectors.

Comment: If you really intend to make THAT MANY connections, you should really solder them or use the correct quick connect.  Otherwise, you're begging for shorts and opens.  If it's that you don't want to solder on to that particular switch, because of it's age or value, buy the switch you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never did specify how permanent you needed the connections to be, but you did imply on the more permanent end by mentioning solder.

The cheapest, most permanent (but not so permanent) way is to loop SOLID wire through the hole and then twist it tightly onto itself, like a twisty tie. I've done this for pots when I'm feeling lazy and non-committal.

You may also want to heatshrink the twist to prevent shorts.

But other than that, there are no connectors for that kind of thing unless you count probe clips as a connector which you can purchase and put onto the ends of any wire you choose (similar to logic analyzer probes or oscilloscope probes). Of course, this is the pricier (far pricier), less permanent end.

[image]

[image]

From EZ-Hook Datasheets

Answer (score 2):

The terminals you show are designed for solder to wire connection.

It may be possible to get Crimp Recepticals (the type that plug on to crimp tab connectors) of small enough size.

[image: Crimp Receptical]

I know it is possible to get ones designed for 2.8 x 0.8mm tab connectors. Whether or not these will provide a reliable connection will depend exactly on the size of your tabs. I certainly wouldn't use them for long-term connection.

Comment: The curled leaves can be opened up to a fairly large height. This allows connecting to a very thick terminal. The important factor is the width of crimp connector. The sizes that I am familiar with are: 0.125", 0.187", 0.250". I'm certain there are other widths available but I've never dealt with them.